# How to send HTTP request to local host database?

Tags: postman, xampp

I have used XAMPP to run Apache and MySQL. Then using phpMyAdmin, I created a database with different tables.

At this point, I am trying to use Postman to send HTTP requests to my database.

I have sent a GET request to 127.0.0.1, which returns the XAMPP Apache + MariaDB + PHP + Perl web page.

I have also sent a GET request to 127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin/ which returns the phpMyAdmin page.

However, I cannot figure out what the correct URL is to access my database or any of the tables in said database.

Comment: MySQL doesn't have direct HTTP access. You need to write PHP scripts that make requests to the DB, and call those with HTTP.

Comment: `phpMyAdmin` is a user interface, not an API.